# Почему в __cdecl результат вызванной функции возвращается через регистр?

Tags: функции, c, стек

Насколько я понял спецификацию, если результат функции целочисленный, он возвращается через регистр `eax`, а если вещественный - то через регистр сопроцессора `st0`.

Это решение мне кажется странным вот по какой причине. Я пробовал писать на C функции, возвращающие структуры, и всё работает. Но структура,  скорее всего, в регистры процессора не влезет, и её придётся возвращать каким-нибудь другим способом (например, вернуть через eax указатель на фрагмент стека, в котором она находилась). Почему было не сделать, как в Паскалевском соглашении: после фактических параметров функции загнать в стек столько байт, сколько требуется для возвращаемого результата, чтобы функция записала его туда?

Comment: @Modus, в отличие от Pascal, в C есть функции с переменным числом аргументов,

а все современные реализации не передают в функцию количество аргументов (жаль, в реализации из Berkeley на VAX это было очень удобно).

Поэтому на этапе компиляции неизвестно, куда надо класть результат.

Comment: А что это меняет? Если загнать в стек сначала все параметры, сколько бы их ни было, а потом - место для результата, то между этим местом и локальными переменными функции будет только адрес возврата. Это, скорее всего, четыре байта. Отступил на четыре байта - вот и известно, куда класть результат. Я полагаю, что функции, возвращающие структуры данных, так и работают.

Comment: @Modus, я просто быстренько глянул, какой asm делает gcc -S на x86. 

Мог и ошибиться. 

Если очень надо, то можно (на досуге) посмотреть повнимательней, с разными образцами кода (но скорее всего уже на x86-64).

Comment: Смотреть повнимательнее не обязательно. Лучше поясните, о чём конкретно речь. Я правильно понял, что когда функция должна вернуть структуру данных, компилятор gcc генерирует код, который после передачи параметров функции загоняет  в стек пустой указатель, а функция при возврате управления заполняет это место стека адресом структуры, которую она вернёт? Но тогда всё равно непонятно, зачем делать это в стеке, если указатель можно положить в eax.

Comment: Не буду утверждать, что внимательно все изучал, но насколько я помню, вчера я увидел, что *вызывающая* функция последним словом перед `call` положила в стек адрес структуры в своей локальной памяти (тоже в стеке), а *вызываемая*, используя этот адрес, копирует результат (несколькими `mov`) туда (в стек вызывающей) из своей локальной памяти (непосредственно перед `ret`).

Comment: Понял, спасибо. По идее, эта схема не будет работать, если вызвать функцию, возвращающую структуру, но не присваивать результат, который вернула функция, локальной переменной вызывающей функции

Comment: Почему? Вот посмотрите


    struct x {
      double a, b, c;
    };
    
    struct x f() { return (struct x){3.62, 2.87, 0.42}; }
    

gcc -S cf.c -O3 (так asm меньше)


    f:
    .LFB39:
            .cfi_startproc
            movl    4(%esp), %eax
            fldl    .LC0
            fstpl   (%eax)
            fldl    .LC1
            fstpl   8(%eax)
            fldl    .LC2
            fstpl   16(%eax)
            ret     $4
            .cfi_endproc
    
К сожалению у меня комментарии закончились, уже удалять пришлось...